# Passing C# variable into aspx Source Sql Query

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

I'm trying to do a messaging system where the inbox is a gridview of all the messages associated with a user's ID. I have a global get method in C# to get the user currently signed in. I'm wondering how to tie this back so that the database only shows the data I want it to.

In my .aspx.cs file, I have something like:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          int userInSess = getLoggedInUser();
          Session["user"] = user;

    }
```

In the source file, I have something like:

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ProjectDB" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [SentByUserName], [Subject], [CreateDate] FROM [Messages] WHERE (ReceivedByUserID = @user) ORDER BY [CreateDate] DESC">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name = "user" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I know this is wrong but I can't seem to find clear answer on how to exactly do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have u tried ,keeping session variable in some local variables and then using the local variables to get the desired result from the database?

Comment: You need to reference the value from the session with `<asp:SessionParameter Name="User" SessionField="user" />` Note the addition of `SessionField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the value stored in the session with:

```
<asp:SessionParameter Name="User" SessionField="user" />
```

Note the addition of `SessionField` attribute.

SqlDataSource control only uses `Name="User"` of the Parameter object to match a @user placeholder in SQL query